# What Ruby On Rails text editor should a beginner use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, text-editor

I am new in creating web applications in Windows. I am planning to do it on Ruby On Rails. However, I am confused what text editor should a beginner use. There are a lot of text editors like GVim, red car editor, sublime text, e-text editor, and ruby mine. What text editor is easier to use for a beginner?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968/best-editor-or-ide-for-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)  is very easy. It has syntax highlighting, but other than that not much fanciness.